# Why am I not getting notifications when a question asker is commenting back on a question?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

I am not getting notifications when the person is commenting on his/her question if I asked something before. For example, in comments

> Me on question: What platform are you using?
>
> Person who asked the question: Android & iOS // no notifications for me

Comment: Is there more than one commentator?

Comment: Unfortunately! I didn't notice that.

Comment: See: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's more than one person in the comments, then to direct your comment to someone explicitly, you have to use @-comments to notify them.  With two people, the system assumes you *two* are having a conversation and does not enforce this requirement.

Comment: If something common on thread or person forgot to mention @ than it's gone. :(

Comment: Nothing is gone; you're just not notified. The comment is still there.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I mean to say that connection won't be there to notify us :)